# How to load javascript file on homepage in Wordpress in order?

Tags: javascript, forms, buttons, comments

I am using a `quicktags` plugin, which was not loading on the home page, now it does, but it does it on the wrong place. How can I solve this?

**I want the quicktags.min.js file to load first, rather than the basic-comment quicktags...**

I am using this script:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ron_scripts' );
function ron_scripts(){
   if(is_home()){
     wp_register_script( 'quicktags', '/wp-includes/js/quicktags.min.js?ver=3.5.1');
     wp_enqueue_script( 'quicktags' );
     wp_register_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags', '/wp-content/plugins/basic-comment-quicktags/quicktags.js' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags' );
     } else {

    }
}
```

What should I do to get it work like I want it to be?

Edit: so now I am using:

```
function quicktags_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'quicktags-min', '/wp-includes/js/quicktags.min.js?ver=3.5.1');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'quicktags-min' );
wp_register_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags', '/wp-content/plugins/basic-comment-quicktags/quicktags.js' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'quicktags_script' );
```

....

Can I get the basic-comment-quicktags beneath all scripts?

Edit 2:

If I change `quicktags-min` to `quicktags`, it does not give me the l10n error and it shows it to me in my page source. This time I get this error: `Permission denied to access property 'toString'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your functions.php:
edit: First register the quicktags script under a different name than already registered in wp "quicktags" , see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

```
function quicktags_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'quicktags-min', '/wp-includes/js/quicktags.min.js?ver=3.5.1','','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'quicktags-min' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'quicktags_script' );
```

This will load the script for all the pages on your front-end.
To load it only on front-page :

```
function quicktags_script() {
    if(is_front_page()){
        wp_register_script( 'quicktags-min', '/wp-includes/js/quicktags.min.js?ver=3.5.1','','',true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'quicktags-min' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'quicktags_script' );
```

Just add the last parameter $in_footer for the wp_register_script to true (see the edited answer) . Or add 'quicktags-min' as the third parameter for the basicktags register function

```
wp_register_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags', '/wp-content/plugins/basic-comment-quicktags/quicktags.js','quicktags-min' );
```

This will first load quicktags-min and then the basictags.

Comment: Thanks man, but now, the problem is the order of the plugins... See my edited post... The question has changed a bit now

Comment: It should work the way you wrote. What is the problem exactly ? Where do you need it to load and why are you loading them both ?

Comment: @Johan I think I got it : edited the answer

Comment: Thanks man, now it is in the correct order indeed. The problem is that it still won't fetch the quicktags.... In `single.php` the plugin script is beneath the whole page source... Quicktags is where it is now... Maybe that's the problem. You have any idea how I can get the enqueued script beneath all scripts? So whole way down?

Comment: See my edit on the post btw

Comment: Just add the last parameter $in_footer for the wp_register_script to true (see the edited answer) . Or add 'quicktags-min' as the third parameter for the basicktags register function `wp_register_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags', '/wp-content/plugins/basic-comment-quicktags/quicktags.js','quicktags-min' );` This will first load quicktags-min and then the basictags.

Comment: Brother, it says `quicktagsL10n is not defined`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9821/discussion-between-johan-and-tolea-bivol)

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) is `$deps`-- dependencies. `wp_enqueue_script` also accepts a `$deps` parameter, by the way.

```
wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

`$deps` is an array of scripts upon which the script being registered depends. Dependencies load *before* the scripts upon which they depend. WordPress will juggle things around for you if you register things correctly.

```
function quicktags_script() {
    wp_register_script( 
       'quicktags-min', 
       '/wp-includes/js/quicktags.min.js?ver=3.5.1'
    );

    wp_register_script( 
       'basic-comment-quicktags', 
       '/wp-content/plugins/basic-comment-quicktags/quicktags.js',
       array('quicktags-min')
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'quicktags-min' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'quicktags_script' );
```

That is what your original question sounded like you wanted. Now, you have rewritten asking how to get "basic-comment-quicktags beneath all scripts". To do that, you probably want to enqueue the script very late with a priority on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. You can register the script as normal and enqueue it like this:

```
function enqueue_bcquicktags() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_bcquicktags', 1000 );
```

You may also want to look into the fifth parameter, `$in_footer`, as that will load your script in the footer of the page. Without that, it should load last in the `<head>` of the page.

Comment: +1, no need to re-register a script, just add a dependency.

Comment: Did I re-register something?

Comment: This still doesn't do a thing. It does load the js files, yes, but I can't see the tags/buttons anyway.... It says `quicktagsL10n is not defined`

Comment: `quicktagsL10n` is nowhere in your question. However, if the scripts load as you say they do, and I assume you mean in the correct order, then the problem is elsewhere-- perhaps with the scripts themselves. Do the scripts depend on the `$` alias by any chance?

Comment: @s_ha_dum if I use my own script (see first post, first code), then I can see in the page source this `quicktagsL10n`, so it has to do with their codes.... If I use their codes, I can't see it anymore. The first code (so my code) gives only this error `quicktags is not defined`

Comment: See my edit btw